# Flutter: Container com dois Expanded e uma imagem de fundo

Tags: flutter, dart

**ATUALIZADO COM O CÓDIGO INTEIRO DA TELA**

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar nessa?

Tenho um ListView, e na construção do seu itemBuilder, pretendo ter um Container dividido por dois Expanded.
Porém, no primeiro Expanded, eu pretendo colocar a imagem de um produto como background, e no segundo suas informações.

Como as informações são dinâmicas, o Container **não pode ter tamanho fixo**. Pois, o segundo expanded pode crescer, e o primeiro deveria acompanhar o segundo na altura.

No código abaixo os textos estão fixos.

Eu só consegui chegar onde cheguei, informando um HEIGHT para o primeiro Expanded, o que eu queria que fosse dinâmico.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewDeliveryEst2 extends StatefulWidget {
  NewDeliveryEst2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _NewDeliveryEstState createState() => _NewDeliveryEstState();
}

class _NewDeliveryEstState extends State<NewDeliveryEst2> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 115, bottom: 0),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return _buildList(context, index);
                    }),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      //height: 110,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
      //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

        children: <Widget>[

          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(17.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(17.0)),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage('https://img.cybercook.com.br/receitas/152/hamburguer-de-carne-moida-2-623x350.jpeg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                ),
              ),
              child: null
            )
          ),
          
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 2, 2, 0),
                      child: Text("Sanduba show debmais",),
                    )),
                    Container(
                      width: 90,
                      height: 30,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(17), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(17)),
                        color: Colors.red
                      ),
                      child: Text("R\$ 22,00", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  child: Text("A expressão Lorem ipsum em design gráfico e editoração é um texto padrão em latim utilizado na produção gráfica para preencher.",),
                )
              ],
            )
            ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }

  _clickOpenProduct() {}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia compartilhar um código executável do seu problema, onde as pessoas possam só copiar e executar. Classes como Styles, Cores e Paddings não existem no SDK (apenas no seu projeto) e fica difícil copiar o código (e ter que corrigí-lo) para tentar reproduzir e te ajudar.

Comment: Vou editar, retirando esses campos, colocando os valores fixos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode conseguir o desejado utilizando o widget [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html).
Ele vai tentar sempre definir o melhor `height` semelhante para os filhos, em outras palavras, se um dos filhos aumenta de tamanho, os demais irão seguir este mesmo tamanho.

Ele deve ser usado com cuidado pois é um Widget custoso, e deve ser evitado se a árvore de Widgets descendentes for grande. Como diz as docs:

> This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative
> layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where
> possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that
> is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.

Entretanto, aqui [um exemplo](https://dartpad.dev/b92bb7fa276ff1d16977152423134ac9) de uso do mesmo para o seu caso, no DartPad.
Note que eu removi várias informações e simplifiquei (afinal o seu código utiliza várias classes e informações que existem no sdk padrão), então ele não estará formatado(estilizado e bonitinho) como você deseja.

Mas já é possível entender que conforme você aumenta o tamanho do texto a imagem seguirá o mesmo `height`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema.